# What happens to the return value( which returns an object ) when it is neglected?

Tags: c++, return-value, copy-constructor

I was going through this particular example in Thinking in C++- Bruce Eckel.I could understand the **statement 1(mentioned in comments ) and statement 2** but had a hard time understanding the **statement 3** when there is no return even if the function declaration and definition requires an object to be returned for copy purposes. Now here what actually happens? For the other two statements (1 and 2) what I could infer was that *compiler prevents bitcopying because we have specified a copy constructor inside our class and instead handles it through the copy-constructor defined by us for the object passed inside the function as well as for the object returned by the function. Just before the end of function the temporary object inside the function is copied for the return value and then destructed*. Am I right in this?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
ofstream out("HowMany2.out");
class HowMany2 {
    string name; // Object identifier
    static int objectCount;
    public:
    HowMany2(const string& id = "") : name(id) {
        ++objectCount;
        print("HowMany2()");
    }
    ~HowMany2() {
       --objectCount;
       print("~HowMany2()");
    }
    // The copy-constructor:
    HowMany2(const HowMany2& h) : name(h.name) {
       name += " copy";
       ++objectCount;
       print("HowMany2(const HowMany2&)");
    }
    void print(const string& msg = "") const {
       if(msg.size() != 0)
       out << msg << endl;
       out << '\t' << name << ": "<< "objectCount = "<< objectCount << endl;
    }
};
int HowMany2::objectCount = 0;
// Pass and return BY VALUE:
HowMany2 f(HowMany2 x) {
    x.print("x argument inside f()");
    out << "Returning from f()" << endl;
    return x;
}
int main() {
    HowMany2 h("h");//statement 1 
    out << "Entering f()" << endl;
    HowMany2 h2 = f(h);//statement 2
    h2.print("h2 after call to f()");
    out << "Call f(), no return value" << endl;
    f(h);//statement 3
    out << "After call to f()" << endl;
}
```

According to Eckel , the output is:

```
HowMany2()
h: objectCount = 1
Entering f()
HowMany2(const HowMany2&)
h copy: objectCount = 2
x argument inside f()
h copy: objectCount = 2
Returning from f()
HowMany2(const HowMany2&)
h copy copy: objectCount = 3
~HowMany2()
h copy: objectCount = 2
h2 after call to f()
h copy copy: objectCount = 2
Thinking in C++ www.BruceEckel.com
Call f(), no return value
HowMany2(const HowMany2&)
h copy: objectCount = 3
x argument inside f()
h copy: objectCount = 3
Returning from f()
HowMany2(const HowMany2&)
h copy copy: objectCount = 4
~HowMany2()
h copy: objectCount = 3
~HowMany2()
h copy copy: objectCount = 2
After call to f()
~HowMany2()
h copy copy: objectCount = 1
~HowMany2()
h: objectCount = 0
```

Also why couldn't we allocate extra storage for the return values so that we can store them there before a function call. Could it be an alternative to using references?
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no copy constructor call since the return value of the function is neglected.
Note that even when a copy might be needed most compilers are allowed to avoid the copy constructor call through **copy elision** under certain circumstances.

Since `x` is object local to the function(*there is a pass by value*), `x` gets destroyed once the function scope `{  }` ends.

Comment: But when we see the output it shows that indeed the copy-constructor was called for the return value and later destructed. That's why I doubted that why shouldn't compiler just neglect the call.

Comment: @KavishDwivedi: Are you sure it is copy constructor call for *return by value*? Note there is a copy constructor call needed for *pass by value* (Your function argument is pass by value) as well. Are you misinterpreting the latter as former?

Comment: :No no , I have just been reading this chapter on copy-constructors for only the second time but the output by Eckel shows that the objectcount is incremented for a copy-constructor.

Comment: @KavishDwivedi: Well, there is no copy required since the return value was never captured and the compiler(*i suspect most of them*) will simply elide the copy constructor call in such a situation. lookup more on copy elision and you should get a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

> For the other two statements (1 and 2) what I could infer was that compiler prevents bitcopying because we have specified a copy constructor inside our class and instead handles it through the copy-constructor defined by us for the object passed inside the function as well as for the object returned by the function. Just before the end of function the temporary object inside the function is copied for the return value and then destructed. Am I right in this?

In C++:

1. The temporary is *move-constructed* from the returned object (if you did not define a move-constructor, this will be a copy-construction); then,
2. The object to which the returned value is assigned is either
   move-assigned (if you used `t = f()`) or move-constructed (if you
   used `T t = f()`) from the returned value (move-assignment becomes copy-assignment if no move-assignment operator is defined, and move-construction becomes copy-construction if no move-constructor is defined); then,
3. The temporary is destructed.

> had a hard time understanding the statement 3 when there is no return even if the function declaration and definition requires an object to be returned for copy purposes

If you just don't use the returned value, there is no real reason for the compiler to invoke any copy-constructor. Your returned object will simply go out of scope when returning from the function, and that's everything.

If you see a call to the copy-construction here, that is probably due to the fact that the compiler failed to optimize away steps 2 and 3 above (the compiler is *allowed*, but not *required*, to elide the call).